# Reference to Object is lost somehow

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects, aurelia

I'm building a fairly advanced app using the Aurelia framework that uses models, services and custom elements.

I have a user model containing username, email etc as well as a bool isLoggedIn.

I have a user service which stores the user in localStorage, allows you to update the user data etc etc.

I finally have some custom elements that use the user service to fetch the current user and display a UI that depends on whether the user is logged in or not.

The issue I'm facing is that after I've fetched the user using the user service, and then update the user model from one of my custom elements (stored in the user service) another custom element's reference to said user model won't update.

I've tried to replicate the issue in a JSFiddle (in plain JS - I'm writing this in ES6) but failed to do so, in the fiddle all works fine.

There's quite a lot of code, but I'd like to hear from you what I might've done wrong for this to happen at all?

Here's the gist of what I have:

**user.model.js**

```
export class User {
    username = '';
    isLoggedIn = false;

    constructor (data) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

**user.service.js**

```
import { User } from 'user.model';

export class UserService {
    constructor () {
        this.user = null;
    }

    getUser () {
        // User is cached
        if (this.user) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.user);
        }

        // Check if we have localStorage
        var user = window.localStorage.getItem('user');

        if (user) {
            this.user = new User(JSON.parse(user));

            return Promise.resolve(this.user);
        }

        // No user - create new
        this.user = new User();

        return Promise.resolve(this.user);
    }

    saveUser () {
        this.getUser().then(() => {
            window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
        });
    }

    updateUser (user) {
        this.getUser().then(() => {
            Object.assign(this.user, user);

            this.saveUser();
        });
    }

    login () {
        this.updateUser({
            isLoggedIn: true
        });

        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

**custom-element.js**

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

import { UserService } from 'user.service';

@inject (UserService)
export class CustomElement {
    constructor (userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    attached () {
        this.userService.getUser().then(user => {
            this.user = user;

            console.log('Fetched user:');
            console.dir(this.user);

            console.log('Same?');
            console.dir(this.user === user); // this is true
        });

        // At some point another custom element fires the UserService.login() method
        // Here we check that our reference to the user also updates

        setInterval(() => {
            console.log('Is user logged in?');
            console.dir(this.user.isLoggedIn); // This is always false - even after UserService.login() has been called and UserService.user is updated (if I console.dir this.user inside UserService it is indeed updated)

            // Grab a new version of UserService.user
            this.userService.getUser().then(user => {
                console.log('Fetched new user, is new user and our user same?');
                console.dir(this.user === user); // false :/ the new user fetched here actually has isLoggedIn === true but our this.user does not...
            });
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments, at one point another custom element runs `UserService.login()` which changes `UserService.user.isLoggedIn` to `true` (this is reflected in the `UserService` if I `console.dir` its `this.user`) but the other `CustomElement`'s `this.user` does *not* update.

Btw: The reason for the `Promise.resolve()` in `UserService.getUser()` is that in the future there will be server calls in there.

Tbh I'm quite new to this type of programming in JS, coming more from a jQuery world, and even though I'm basically in love with Aurelia stuff like this still confuse me greatly so hoping for some insight here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code you provided, I don't see what would cause the behavior you've described.

One suggestion- to make your code a little easier to manage, less async...  what if you structured it like this:

*user.js*

```js
export class User {
  loggedIn = false;
  name = 'Anonymous';
}
```

*user-store.js*

```js
@inject(User)
export class UserStore {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  load() {
    const serializedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (!info) {
      return;
    }
    const storageUser = JSON.parse(serializedUser);
    this.user.loggedIn = storageUser.loggedIn;
    this.user.name = storageUser.name;
  }

  save() {
    const serializedUser = JSON.stringify(this.user);
    localStorage.setItem('user', serializedUser);
  }
}
```

*auth-service.js*

```js
@inject(User, UserStore)
export class AuthService {
  constructor(user, store) {
    this.user = user;
    this.store = store;
  }

  login(username, password) {
    return fetch('https://api.megacorp.com/login', { method: 'POST' ... })
      .then(result => {
        this.user.loggedIn = true;
        this.user.name = result.name;
        this.store.save();
      });
  }
}
```

*custom-element.js*

```js
@inject(User)
export class CustomElement {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  ...
}
```

The benefit being your custom elements never need to take a dep on something async. They just get the application's User instance, whose properties might change but will always remain the same instance.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow... What you're doing differently is that instead of `UserStore.user` being a `new User()` it is in fact _the_ user model? Would this not prevent me from using the user model elsewhere? Also, would you recommend having a separate `AuthService`? I've basically made this whole system up myself without reading too much about how one _should_ structure something like this. If you have a link to a tutorial or article about OOP authentication/user handling in JS I'd love to read it.

Comment: you could combine the UserStore and the AuthStore, there's no hard rule, do what works best for you. The main thing I was trying to demonstrate is the things that depend on the User do not need an async API. They can access the user instance via taking a dependency on it (using `@inject`). The things that *act* on the user (moving it from an anonymous state to a logged-in state) may be async (the AuthService is async but the UserStore isn't).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to experiment a bit with this to see if I understand everything. But is it correct that the main difference in your code is that you set `UserService.user` to the actual `User` class as opposed to an instance of the `User` class (using `new User()`)? Is that why when I later inject the same `User` class in my custom elements they will be the same?

Comment: Should I perhaps declare a variable such as this in my root component (`app.js`) and simply pass it along to child components? If so, do you know how that's done in Aurelia?

Comment: the main difference in my example is the `User` instance is managed by the container (by default a singleton). The CustomElement, UserStore, AuthService all depend on the user instance (via `@inject(User)`).  The container will ensure they all get the same instance.  I was thinking this was a more natural fit because it removed the async complications *and* solved the issue you posted about.

Comment: Ok thanks, again I will experiment a little with this and come back :)

Comment: One absolutely crazy thing that I just noticed is that the very same custom element uses another property from the user object (an array) which _does_ get updated... Starting to think my problem lies elsewhere in the code. FYI; I've now moved all the auth stuff from `UserService` to an `AuthService`. This does feel cleaner. I have yet to experiment with injecting the User object however.

Comment: I've yet to try injecting the user as you suggested because tbh I don't really understand how that works :P And I would need to change quite a lot of code. I have however moved all auth stuff to another service, and this solved my problem for now. I'll give you the answer for pointing me in the right direction, and I'll probably give injecting the user a go in the future. Thanks